# r converting 2 variables from row to columns in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a dataset with 3 fields id|FeatureName|Volume of feature

```
id  log_feature volume
6597    feature 68  6
8011    feature 68  7
2597    feature 68  1
5022    feature 172 2
5022    feature 56  1
5022    feature 193 4
5022    feature 71  3
6852    feature 201 2
6852    feature 56  1
```

I have to convert this dataset from rows to columns ie

```
id  volume1 feature 1   Volume 172 feature 172  Volume 56 feature 56    ...
5022|0  |0    |2  | 1 | 1 |1 .....
```

ie the resulting data set should have one row per id ,volume given is that of the feature next to it .
In the sample above i have taken the example of id=5022 but the column in the result dataset will contain ALL the columns possible in source data set and corresponding volume.
How can i achieve this in R -Please help

Comment: use `tidyr::spread`?

Comment: @chinsoon12 :please look at the final format of data ,i wanted feature/Volume as a pair and not  logfeatohe=logfeature %>% spread(key=log_feature,value=volume,fill=0)

Comment: Your desired output is not very clear. Can you add separators in the header row as well?